# My son's tablet has been stolen and I am trying to locate it..

Tags: tablet

I had installed the Android device locator on my son's tablet should it ever get lost or stolen and I had tried locating it my several first tries were a failure as it said that the device was unable to be located. But at those points I had three options "ring, lock and erase" so I chose to lock it but was unsure if it worked, so I repeated this step like 2 more times. Checking to see if the device has been located frequently,  I had noticed at one point in time the device was turned on and located (was unable to find exact location because the session had expired, so I had to relog in) but then I noticed at this time my options were different saying "ring or enable lock and wipe" so I pressed enable lock and wipe and it said "request sent to lock and wipe admin features..Does anybody know what this means?

Answer (score 3):

You can't track the device after factory resetting it, since it removes the Android Device Manager and/or its settings.  It is purely for preventing your information from being accessed.